# Would selling land at a low price to someone of the same surname indicate a familial relationship?

Tags: 18th-century, land, south-carolina

Using family bible records, deeds, and census records, I have traced my Fulton family line to my 3rd great grandfather Gersham Fulton in Anderson District South Carolina. But I am now at a dead end.

The earliest record I have found is a deed where he purchased about 200 acres for only 10 shillings from a Samuel Fulton in 1791 or 92. Samuel had been granted the land from the governor only 6 months eariler.

I thought the low price might indicate that Samuel was a relative, the father or perhaps an uncle of Gersham. Also, Gersham’s first son was named Samuel.

What else could that price indicate?

Maybe Gersham was an indentured servant?

Maybe he was an illegitimate son of Samuel?

Or am I reading some significance into the price and that is not there?

I have not been able to connect Gersham to Samuel. Gersham’s second son was named Jesse and there was a Samuel and a Jesse in North Carolina who were brothers but I can not make a connection there either.

I believe Gersham married and started his family about the time of the land purchse.

Comment: It certainly does *indicate* (but not prove) a familial relationship, possibly a nephew.  I don't know whether an illegitimate child would carry the bio-father's name, the mother's name or -- if the mother married -- that man's name.

Answer (score 2):

I've always been on the side of taking a grain of salt with leaning towards believing there was a familial connection.  From just a single deed we don't know if there might be other obligations one way or the other that influenced the sale.   Maybe the grantor was a court appointed guardian to the grantee in years past due to a close relationship with the parents, but no familial relationship actually existed.  An individual in that situation might sell cheap as it were. 
 Bottom line is I lean towards there being a connection 9 times out of 10, but I always keep my mind open to other possibilities until I can form a more clear picture of the possible relationship between the individuals or their families.